# How to quit from a group conversation iMessage?

Tags: macos, ios, messages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to “unsubscribe” from group texts in iOS 5?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32142/is-there-a-way-to-unsubscribe-from-group-texts-in-ios-5)

I am trying to quit a annoying iMessage conversation. You know, when someone send messages to multiple users, so everyone receive the same messages. It's like a group chat.

How to quit a conversation?

Comment: Great description of the problem. I'll link this to out main question on the topic.